# I am getting a type error for the keyword I used in schema

Tags: python, typeerror, flask-sqlalchemy

```
from flask import Flask,jsonify
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy
# Marshmallow is an object serialization/deserialization library
#from flask_marshmallow import Marshmallow
from marshmallow_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemySchema
from marshmallow import Schema
import os
import jsonpickle

app = Flask(__name__)

# the name of the database; add path if necessary
db_name = 'student.db'

basedir = os.path.abspath(os.path.dirname(__file__))
app.config['SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI'] = 'sqlite:///' + os.path.join(basedir, db_name)

app.config['SQLALCHEMY_TRACK_MODIFICATIONS'] = True

# this variable, db, will be used for all SQLAlchemy commands
db = SQLAlchemy()
db.init_app(app)


# Import each table from model.py to app.py so that Flask can run
from models.model import Tutor

with app.app_context():
    db.create_all()

#Create tutor schema
class TutorSchema(SQLAlchemySchema):
    class Meta:
        fields = ('tutor_id','tutor_forename','tutor_surname','tutor_email','tutor_category','module_id')
        
# In it schema
tutor_schema = TutorSchema(strict = True)
tutors_schema = TutorSchema(many =True,strict = True)

@app.route('/', methods = ['GET'])
def tefetchLessonsByTutorst():
    
    lessons = Tutor.query.all()
    results = tutors_schema.dump(lessons)
    
    return jsonify( results)
```

I am trying to get a response in json format and I am getting this error. When I remove the many and strict argument I am getting {} .Please help me.

> TypeError: __init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'strict'

Answer (score 1):

I was able to resolve the issue. I have done the following changes.

I removed strict keyword, now my code look like this

```
tutors_schema = TutorSchema(many =True)
```

Also I have done following changes

```
#Create tutor schema
class TutorSchema(Schema):
class Meta:
    fields = ('tutor_id','tutor_forename','tutor_surname','tutor_email','tutor_category','module_id')

tutor_schema = TutorSchema(many =True)
```

and I use this import

```
from marshmallow import Schema
```